# Read, parse and display .csv file with Shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny

While there are bits and pieces, I haven't found anything as specific as the problem I'm dealing with at the moment so I'm going to ask. Sorry for the length but I wanted to be as detailed as possible.

I'm able to read "file.csv" (who's content is shown below) with read.csv. Now I want to parse and display the content of the file using Shiny (I'm running RStudio IDE).

```html
Name City  State  Type   QtySold     QtyBought 
A Chicago  Illinois Seller     200
B Jersey City New Jersey Buyer             300
C Oakland  California Both        450         200
D Akron  Ohio  Buyer          330
E Madison  Wisconsin Seller     600
```

I modified the **ui.R** [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html) for Shiny to display these tabs as below:

```html
DataTable Options   GeoMap   Sellers    Buyers   OtherStuff
```

I would like to modify these **server.R** and **ui.R** [files](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html) to accomplish the following:

Read the file, go thru the "Type" column, grab and group all the types and write them to the respective tab (in Shiny), ranking them based on "QtyBought" and "QtySold".

So when it's all said and done, when you click on "Seller" and "Buyer" tabs (in Shiny) you will see something like this:

**Seller Tab:**

```html
Rank Name City  State  Type  Qty
1 E Madison  Wisconsin Seller  600
2 C Oakland  California Seller  450
3 A Chicago  Illinois Seller  200
```

**Buyer Tab:**

```html
Rank Name  City  State  Type  Qty 
1 D  Akron  Ohio  Buyer  330
2 B  Jersey City New Jersey Buyer  300
3 C  Oakland California Buyer  200
```

Comment: anyone with some ideas on how i can accomplish this, please?

Comment: is anything about my question just not clear or it's just not that interesting to people? curious